# What are the most valuable certification available for Programming?

Tags: php, javascript, python, programming-languages, certificate

I would like to know what are the certificates available for programming, like

- Zend for PHP
- SUN Certification for java

What are the others? Javascript? C++? Python? etc...

Please give me some suggestion for other available certifications.

Comment: I think the most valuable certificate is called experience.

Comment: Experience is of course the real thing. But you can't show your experience to a human resources guy who probably doesn't know anything about development. Some certifications are really worth the time and money when you're looking for a job and some will actually show you how to improve your skills while preparing for the exams.

Answer (score 16):

Most valuable thing for a developer: being able to show you can convert requirements into working and maintainable software.

Certifications generally are worth very little, except in a few niches that demand them (or at least ask, until they give up and get someone who puts practice before pieces of paper).

Comment: +1 the only valid certification out there is showing what you have already done. Pieces of paper are just pieces of paper, unless there's a nice symbol on it (€$£¥)

Answer (score 7):

Let me be bold and say that your **Experience** is your best certificate.

Comment: That's not being bold. That's stating what everyone on this site knows.

Comment: @Coronatus, well, the word 'Experience' is in bold :-)

Answer (score 2):

I second the opinion voiced here that the only valid certifications are experience and the work done by you so far. However you might want to check out these two link - [prominent programming certifications](http://certification.about.com/cs/beginner/a/progcerts.htm) and a [discussion on slashdot](http://ask.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=06/10/06/0337209) on a similar subject.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET the most valuable certificates are MCP certificates. Some of them are good for C++ too.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Certified_Professional

In PHP for there is the W3C certification (it exists js, and other programming languages to) http://www.w3schools.com/cert/cert_php.asp

I think these certifications are very valuable.

Answer (score 0):

For linux (implies perl/bash)
Comptia+ 
Red Hat Certified Engineer